# Unhandled Rejection (TypeError): getNotes is not a function in react?

Tags: reactjs

i'm learning react so i created a simple application to manage notes with a title and a description.

I create a getNotes function in Note.js file and i passed the getNotes function to NoteForm and NoteList component.

getNotes is working fine in NoteForm component but it is not working in NoteList component. getNotes() function is used to update the list of Notes. please tell me why getNotes() function is   not working in NoteList

Note.js

```
    function Notes() {
  const [notes, setNotes] = useState([]);

   const getNotes = async () => {
    const notesRes = await axios.get("http://localhost:5000/notes/");   
    setNotes(notesRes.data);
    console.log(notes);
  }

  useEffect(() => {
    getNotes();
  }, []);

  return (
    <div>
      <NoteForm getNotes={getNotes} />
      <NoteList notes={notes} getNotes = {getNotes}/>
        
    </div>
  );
}

export default Notes;
```

Noteform.js

```
function NoteForm({ getNotes }) {
  const [Title, setTitle] = useState("");
  const [description, setDesc] = useState("");
 
  async function saveNote(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    try {
      const noteData = {
        title: Title,
        desc: description,
      };
      await axios.post("http://localhost:5000/notes/", noteData);
      getNotes();
      
      setTitle(''); setDesc('');
      
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  }

  return (...);
}

export default NoteForm;
```

NoteList.js

```
function NoteList({notes}, {getNotes}) {
  //------------Delete-----------
  async function delNote (id) {
    await axios.delete(`http://localhost:5000/notes/${id}`);
    getNotes();
    
  }

  //------------Update-----------

  const [open, setOpen] = React.useState(false);
  const [UpdateTitle, setUpdateTitle] = useState("");
  const [UpdateDescription, setUpdateDescription] = useState("");

  const handleClickOpen = (title, desc) => {
    setUpdateTitle(title);
    setUpdateDescription(desc);
    setOpen(true);
  };

  async function updateNote(id, updatetitle, updatedesc ) {
    const res = await axios.put("http://localhost:5000/notes/", {id, updatetitle, updatedesc});
    handleClose();
    getNotes();
         
  }

  const handleClose = () => {
    setOpen(false);
  };

  

  // ---------------------------

  function renderNotes() {
    return notes.map((note, i) => {
      return <div style={{ display:"inline-block",borderStyle: "ridge", padding:"20px", borderEndStartRadius: "50px", borderBlockEndColor:"yellowgreen", borderStartEndRadius:"50px", margin:"10px" }}
       
       key={i}> <b>Title: </b>  {note.title} <br/> 
       <b>Description: </b> {note.desc} <br/>
       
       <button onClick = {()=> delNote(note._id) } >Delete</button>
       <div>
      <Button variant="contained" style = {{ marginTop: "10px"  , padding: "0.5px"}} onClick={()=>handleClickOpen(note.title, note.desc)}>
      Edit
      </Button>

      <Dialog open={open} onClose={handleClose}>
        <DialogTitle>Update Your Note</DialogTitle>
        <DialogContent>
          {/* <DialogContentText>
            To subscribe to this website, please enter your email address here. We
            will send updates occasionally.
          </DialogContentText> */}
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            onChange={(e) => {
            setUpdateTitle(e.target.value);
          }}
            value = {UpdateTitle}
            label="Title"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
          />
          <TextField
            autoFocus
            margin="dense"
            id="name"
            onChange={(e) => {
            setUpdateDescription(e.target.value);
          }}
            value = {UpdateDescription}
            label="Description"
            type="email"
            fullWidth
            variant="standard"
          />
        </DialogContent>
        <DialogActions>
          <Button onClick={handleClose}>Cancel</Button>
          <Button onClick={()=> updateNote(note._id, UpdateTitle, UpdateDescription )}>Update</Button>
        </DialogActions>
      </Dialog>
    </div>
      
      </div>;
      
    }).reverse();
  }

  return (
    <div>
      <div >
      {renderNotes()}
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}

export default NoteList;
```

Answer (score 0):

```
function NoteList({notes}, {getNotes}) {
```

this must be like this

```
function NoteList({notes, getNotes}) {
```

or

```
 function NoteList(props) {
   ...    
   props.getNotes()
```

Answer (score 0):

You are destructuring the `NoteList` component props wrong. change it to,

```js
function NoteList({ notes, getNotes }) {
```

Comment: @sonukkc Kindly accept the answer if found useful :)